# Best way to substract form input fields html

Tags: php, regex, forms, xpath, grep

How would you best get all the input fields (text, radiobutton, checkbox, select etc) semi-automatically out of dodgy formatted html documents?

Trying to get the `TYPE,NAME,VALUE` and `OPTION` for `SELECT`.

I am currently using Xpath (in PHP) because everyone here says 'use that instead' but I'm getting nowhere with it. So I am open to suggestions. I have a shell present, so it may be 'ordinary' grep too.

Thanks.
Matt

Comment: what are you trying to do? Are you just trying to find their locations? Or actually modify them?

Comment: These are static forms, I'm trying to get them in a list (type -> name -> value-and-or-options) as I need to rebuild them (in a CMS)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery framework in conjunction with good old Firebug (a Firefox addon). jQuery's selector engine will make it easy for you to find all instances of form elements. And Firebug will happily log it to the Javascript console of Firefox.

As you said: this is SEMI-AUTOMATIC.

**EDIT**

To get you started you may want to take a look at [jQuery's API](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) (it has a handy serialize method that aids you big time).

Comment: Thanks, its a cool idea, but my preference would (obviously) be somewhat more automated (ie in a commandline or (php) script).

Comment: No problem, you could send your result via AJAX to a script and ... you know. Once again, jQuery will be your friend here.